# LUIS Portal - Review endpoint utterances : Delete suggestion fails

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am running into errors in the LUIS portal and I'm not sure what is causing them. Whenever I try to delete some utterances from the "Review endpoint utterances" page for my app, it's failing for many of them [(see attached screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENtVb.png). I have multiple apps in my account and realized the issue spans across all of them.  I don't see a correlation between the utterances and their length, characters, etc.  It seems pretty random.  Here are some examples of utterances that I can't delete:

1. why does
2. if so
3. what does it me 5 seller accounts

Is anyone else having similar issues and is aware of a solution? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This is strange, you should be able to utterances from the review list, and I was able to confirm it works as expected. Are you still experiencing this issue, maybe try a different browser?

Comment: Have you retrained/ republish your model?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue

Comment: To further clarify, I have tried training and publishing the model and that doesn't help.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue when I review endpoint utterances. This started happening recently.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the update, we will investigate further and get back to you shortly.

Comment: were these utterances recently created or have they existed for a while now?

Comment: @GiftA-MSFT looks like the utterances under the Review Endpoint Utterances according to the screenshot.

Comment: @GiftA-MSFT We're seeing errors mainly with recently created utterances (over the last 1-2 weeks)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The the product team are aware of this issue and currently working on a fix. Will follow up once we have more details.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: We are still working on it and expecting the fix to take effect by next week. Will followup with you accordingly.

Comment: It seems to be resolved now?

Comment: Yes, the fix has been deployed. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Yes it is good from my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have deployed a fix to resolve this issue.

Comment: Update: We are seeing the same issue again as of yesterday 8/5/2020. Please let me know if you need any additional information to look into the issue further. @GiftA-MSFT

Comment: Hello, thanks for bringing this up, will look into it and share updates soon. Can you please confirm if you are still observing this issue as of 08/10/2020?

Comment: We are confirming with our customer and will post back once we hear from them

Comment: FYI our customer was able to delete the problematic utterance without error, so I'm not sure if you fixed something on your end or if it's an intermittent issue? We will let you know if we see the error again in the coming days.